# How to make responsive web page render faster?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Right now, every time I try to render a page, I will calculate the `$(window).width()` first and then add a corresponding class for the root `html` element, which will final determine the block width of some main responsive elements in the page. But this approach goes with a problem. It will first render the page with a initial default width, and then after the class is added, it will  adjust the element width, which will create a non-smooth visual effect.

To overcome this, I then make all the responsive elements `display: none` in the first place and make them visible after the width calculation is done. But for a user, it takes more time to see the page in this way.

So I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this responsive page in a more efficient and faster way?

Comment: you will do much better on google if your content isn't hidden to anyone loading the page without js.

Comment: Are you waiting for page load to add the class? You shouldn't have to. Since your `window` and `<html>` are available by the time you reach any JS, you should be able to update the `<html>` tag before you load the body.

Comment: @dandavis oh, I didn't even realize this part. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `javascript` to create a responsive site, there are much easier ways.

For example, there are **TONS** of free `CSS` based frameworks you can utilize to make responsive pages that the `CSS` controls, which doesn't eat up *nearly* as many resources as a `javascript` solution. Lots of `DOM` manipulation with `javascript` can get pretty hairy pretty quickly.

**My suggestion would be to look into some of the following:**

- **Foundation:** http://foundation.zurb.com/index.html
- **Skeleton:** http://www.getskeleton.com/

I personally use `foundation` for my development, as its easy to read/understand and it produces rapid development.

**Example:** http://www.sinsysonline.com/secondhomehostel

If you are ABSOLUTELY dead set on having `Javascript` handle your `DOM` rendering, it's going to be much slower than a CSS `responsive` site.

**If so, try out:**

- **Response JS:** http://responsejs.com/

If you would like further clarification for a specific problem, could you please provide your code and I'm more than happy to provide some feedback on that.

Answer (score 1):

CSS media queries allow you to apply CSS based on screen size. The advantages of this over your approach are:

1) The CSS will read the window size immediately
2) The page will automatically adjust if the user resizes the window (or rotates their tablet)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: This is a great solution if you wanted to customize exact sizes and whatnot for how your page will display (mobile, tablet, desktop, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css3 media queries which is very useful to create responsive website. You need to write css according to viewport width. Please refer the [link](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) from which you will get all the idea about responsive website.

I hope this will help yo to work on the responsive websites.